# Is the Man-Mountain Agreement a satire of a specific event?

Tags: gullivers-travels, jonathan-swift

*Gulliver's Travels*, is a story by Jonathan Swift that is widely accepted to be a satire. In it when Gulliver visits Lilliput he agrees to a set of articles about his presence, which read as follows:

> Golbasto Momarem Evlame Gurdilo Shefin Mully Ully Gue, most mighty
>   Emperor of Lilliput, delight and terror of the universe, whose
>   dominions extend five thousand blustrugs (about twelve miles in
>   circumference) to the extremities of the globe; monarch of all
>   monarchs, taller than the sons of men; whose feet press down to the
>   centre, and whose head strikes against the sun; at whose nod the
>   princes of the earth shake their knees; pleasant as the spring,
>   comfortable as the summer, fruitful as autumn, dreadful as winter: his
>   most sublime majesty proposes to the man-mountain, lately arrived at
>   our celestial dominions, the following articles, which, by a solemn
>   oath, he shall be obliged to perform:—
>
> 1st, The man-mountain shall not depart from our dominions, without our
>   license under our great seal.
>
> 2d, He shall not presume to come into our metropolis, without our
>   express order; at which time, the inhabitants shall have two hours
>   warning to keep within doors.
>
> 3d, The said man-mountain shall confine his walks to our principal
>   high roads, and not offer to walk, or lie down, in a meadow or field
>   of corn.
>
> 4th, As he walks the said roads, he shall take the utmost care not to
>   trample upon the bodies of any of our loving subjects, their horses,
>   or carriages, nor take any of our subjects into his hands without
>   their own consent.
>
> 5th, If an express requires extraordinary despatch, the man-mountain
>   shall be obliged to carry, in his pocket, the messenger and horse a
>   six days journey, once in every moon, and return the said messenger
>   back (if so required) safe to our imperial presence.
>
> 6th, He shall be our ally against our enemies in the island of
>   Blefuscu, and do his utmost to destroy their fleet, which is now
>   preparing to invade us.
>
> 7th, That the said man-mountain shall, at his times of leisure, be
>   aiding and assisting to our workmen, in helping to raise certain great
>   stones, towards covering the wall of the principal park, and other our
>   royal buildings.
>
> 8th, That the said man-mountain shall, in two moons’ time, deliver in
>   an exact survey of the circumference of our dominions, by a
>   computation of his own paces round the coast.
>
> Lastly, That, upon his solemn oath to observe all the above articles,
>   the said man-mountain shall have a daily allowance of meat and drink
>   sufficient for the support of 1724 of our subjects, with free access
>   to our royal person, and other marks of our favour.  Given at our
>   palace at Belfaborac, the twelfth day of the ninety-first moon of our
>   reign.

Is this to satirize a specific agreement or only a general satire of European over-formality?